# Исчезновение EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Можно ли при выполнении какого-то события,чтобы EditText переставал отображаться. В данный момент сделал его не кликабельным, но надо чтобы он вообще пропадал.

Comment: или setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вот так вроде

```
setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

или

```
setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

разница:

-- при `INVISIBLE` на месте объекта остается пустое место

-- при `GONE` не место объекта сдвигается следующий объект ( если он есть) - объект невидим и не занимает место